# sqlite CLI: escaping again

Tags: bash, sqlite

In sqlite CLI in which no prepared statements are available: is it safe just to escape potential single quotes in string values and double quotes in column and table names, and wrap them accordingly in queries to prevent potential problems with user-entered data?

E.g. in bash with:

```
escSqlObject() {
    local q='""'
    echo "${1//\"/$q}"
}

escSqlString() {
    local q="''"
    echo "${1//\'/$q}"
}
```

[**Edit**: the above functions seem to be bash-version-agnostic -- thanks to @4ae1e1 for suggestion and to @Baruchel for pointing out a problem with the previous solution.]

do the following:

```
str=$(escSqlString "$1")
int=$2
printf "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
    col1 = '%s' AND col2 = %d;" "$str" "$int" | sqlite3 mydb.db
```

or (security concerns about providing access to sensitive data aside):

```
tbl=$(escSqlObject "$1")
col=$(escSqlObject "$2")
printf 'SELECT "%s" FROM "%s";' "$col" "$tbl" | sqlite3 mydb.db
```

Comment: I don't know sqlite so I'm not in the position to answer your question, but from a bash stand point, it is better to use bash's builtin replacement mechanism to achieve the same result, which is cheaper: `${object//\"/\"\"}`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Good point. The backslashes decrease readability, but it's a minor concern.

Comment: You can also use single quotes to quote the double quotes if you'd like to. I personally find a string of mixed quotes extremely confusing, more so in a bad font.